# How to change the order of the attributes of an XML element using Perl and XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am new to [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig). I want to change the order of the attributes of all `<product>` elements as shown below.

**Input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <product markup="xml" type="books" id="book1">
    <name>Analysis</name>
    <prize>$203</prize>
    <subject>Construct</subject>
  </product>
  <product markup="xml" type="books" id="book2">
    <name>Analysis</name>
    <prize>$203</prize>
    <subject>Bio</subject>
  </product>
</root>
```

I need like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <product id="book1" markup="xml" type="books">
    <name>Analysis</name>
    <prize>$203</prize>
    <subject>Construct</subject>
  </product>
  <product id="book2" markup="xml" type="books">
    <name>Analysis</name>
    <prize>$203</prize>
    <subject>Bio</subject>
  </product>
</root>
```

My code is:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $XML = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers   => {
    #'product' => sub {$_},
    # (I don't know this process)
  },
  pretty_print    => 'record',
  output_encoding => 'utf-8',
  keep_atts_order => 1,
);

$XML->parsefile("input.xml");

$XML->purge;
```

How can I change this?

Comment: This seems to be a strange request. Please would you explain something of *why* you want this reordering? The [XML 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) says explicitly that the order of attributes isn't significant.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a weird request. You're probably trying to do something the wrong way ( or you are working with tools that don't really implement XML fully).

In any case, since XML::Twig by default outputs attribute in alphabetical order, and alphabetically `id` comes before `markup`, which comes before `type`, it looks like you don't have to do anything. Remove the `keep_atts_order` option, read and write the file, voilà! I suspect most other XML tools will behave this way too.

Comment: I think the requirement is to have some *control* over the order of the attributes. Suggesting that dictionary order fulfils this specific need doesn't constitute a solution. I am also surprised if `XML::Twig` bothers to sort the attribute identifiers, and doubt very much that *"most other XML tools will behave this way too"*.

Comment: predictable order is good, it avoids changing a file unecessarily. The initial requirement is not clear to me, so there is is a significant change that in fact it is to sort the attributes alphabetically. We'll see what the OP has to say about it.